# Is there an elegant way to define orthogonality (and/or angles) without inner products, metrics, or norms?

Tags: geometry, inner-products, orthogonality

I was wondering if there is an elegant and intrinsic way to define orthogonality on vectors without introducing inner products? Obviously "elegance" is subjective, so I'll try and give a sketch of the type of thing I'm looking for and why.

I'm not looking for an answer which amounts to "define it with an inner product then forget everything but the angles by modding out the lengths of vectors". It would be nice (but not necessary) if the definition never invoked the reals at all, and had a more pure, geometric character, a little closer to Euclid than abstract algebra.

My motivation is in large part that I'm from the physics world, where vectors are often physical, spatial quantities, where inner products depend on our arbitrary choice of units and are thus non-fundamental (although useful, and unique once we do arbitrarily fix our units). In such a context, defining orthogonality in terms of inner products becomes philosophically problematic and unpleasing. Because of this, I would be satisfied with an inner-product-free definition that only works for finite dimensional real vector spaces, but naturally I'd be happy if it extended as far as possible.

In my mind this feels like a natural step between metric notions and topological, in the sense that it's more general and deep than specific metrics, but gives more form and structure to a space than mere topology. Don't take this too seriously, however.

If such a notion could be generalised even further beyond vector spaces, I would be very happy.

Comment: If you are ok with a norm, then $x$ and $y$ are orthogonal when $\|x+y\|^2 = \|x\|^2 + \|y\|^2$.

Comment: I am not sure, but I suspect you cannot define orthogonality in an abstract vector space, without some additional structure.

Comment: Please re-read the title.

Comment: In a sense inner products are natural, because they are related by a linear transformation. The arbitrary aspect is not so bad.

Comment: I know that an abstract vector space on its own lacks the necessary structure, what I'm looking for is an elegant way of defining additional structure such that we recover orthogonality without resorting to notions like inner products/norms/metrics.

Comment: Inner product is natural. If $x, y$ are orthogonal to $z$, then $ax+by$ is also orthogonal to $z$. In a way this is a "bilinear symmetric property".

Comment: @lEm n inner product imposes a length onto vectors, and I don't want that, for reasons I detail in my question. And defining orthogonality in terms of inner products modulo a scalar hurts my soul. I am interested in this question from a GEOMETRIC position.

Comment: It is unclear what notion do you want. It seems to me that you are asking for a notion that does precisely what inner product does, but not an inner product. Maybe let me ask first, what properties of orthogonality do you want to keep? Orthogonality does not come for free, there is no intrinsic notion of orthogonality in vector spaces. There are always infinite numbers of ways to define it.

Comment: @lEm Firstly, for clarity, I understand that an abstract vector space in itself has no notion of orthogonality in itself. If we impose extra structure in the form of an inner product, we define a notion of orthogonality on that space, but we also define a norm, a vector length. For the geometrically motivated reasons I describe in my question body, I don't want this. What I want, is some (simply, elegant) structure to impose on a vector space which creates a notion of orthogonality, without the baggage of norms/lengths.

Comment: Again, what properties of orthogonality do you want to keep? I mean, in the extreme case, we could just define every vector to be orthogonal to each other, but that will be useless. And honestly I don't think there is any simpler/more elegant notion than an inner product. It's true that there is a natural induced norm and metric associated to the inner product. But you can ignore them, the definition of an inner product does not talk about distance or length or angles. In fact there is nothing stopping me from defining another norm on an inner product space, as weird as it may be.

Comment: The truth is, to define orthogonality, you will need to make a choice of what vectors are orthogonal. In that sense, isn't this as "unnatural" as how inner product requiring you to choose what vectors are orthonormal?

Comment: @lEm I'd want to keep all the properties of orthogonality. All of them, because they are geometrical properties, which is what I'm interested in. And I'd want to do it nicely. I've vaguely heard that you can do it with something called an orthogonal complement function whose arguments and values are linear subspaces (I think), defined purely axiomatically, but I've not had luck googling.

Comment: @lEm From a geometrical perspective, no, it's not as "unnatural". With respect to geometry, norms/lengths are arbitrary, but orthogonality is important and intrinsic. Lengths are unnatural in a similar way to co-ordinates, although in a less extreme way. Again, I care about vectors as geometric entities, not algebraic ones.

Comment: The problem is that unless you weaken the notion of orthogonality so much as to make it useless, using transformations that preserve orthogonality lets you say when two line segments have the same length, so you won't get anything other than inner products modulo a scalar. If you google for "axiomatizations of geometry" you will find there has been quite a lot of work on this in the logical literature, but (probably for the reason I have just given) it hasn't had much influence on mainstream mathematics.

Comment: @RobArthan I'm perfectly happy with a notion of orthogonality from which we could recover an inner product modulo a scalar, so long as it does not privilege one inner product over another, and is not axiomatised in terms of equivalences of inner products or some other similar notion which would defeat the spirit of what I'm asking.

I'll look into axiomatisations of geometry then, that sounds interesting, but for now would you be able to give such a definition as I'd find there, or direct me to one?

It feels odd that this would be outside of the mainstream.

Comment: First off, orthogonality is not any more natural than lengths. You got that wrong impression because you are thinking about $\mathbb R^n$, on which lengths and angles are "natural" as $\mathbb R^n$ can be defined using real numbers. But if you so insist, I would imagine the axiomatic way to something like the following: let $L(V)$ be the set of all linear subspaces of $V$, then an orthogonal complement function is a bijective mapping $T:L(V) \to L(V)$ such that $T\circ T=\operatorname{Id}$, and for any subspace $U$, $U\oplus T(U) =V$. (I imagine there could be a couple more rules)

Comment: @lEm Thanks. But I'd disagree with your assessment, given that my question was clearly and explicitly based on considering vectors geometrically first and foremost. There's a reason I have kept repeating that I'm not caring about vectors as algebraic objects, just geometric ones. The abstract algebra is fine, it's just not what this question was about.

Comment: The "intrinsic geometry" comes from $\mathbb R^n$ itself, but not the vector space structure. Any vector space doesn't naturally come with a notion of orthogonality nor angle, it has no geometry in it. The geometry comes from an extra structure, and it is precisely the inner product. I think you should read more about the rigorous mathematical into vector spaces etc before asking this question. What you said about "geometry", "intrinsic" etc are not mathematical, they are only used in a laymen-manner. Can you define what the difference between an algebraic vectors and a geometric vectors?

Comment: @lEm I'm perfectly familiar with treating vectors in a mathematically rigorous way. Saying "the geometry comes from an extra structure, and it is precisely the inner product" is simply and utterly false. The geometric properties of a vector space do not depend on it, but simply on notions of relative length. In my question I said I'd be perfectly happy if a sensible geometric notion of orthogonality could only be defined for real vector spaces, so I'm happy to stay in $\mathbb{R}^n$ if such a notion requires it.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you may be looking for something like projective space. This is no longer a vector space, but an inner product exists that has no well defined value other than it either being zero or nonzero.

Projective space is a quotient of a vector space minus the origin that identifies two vectors if they are scalar multiples of each other. In an inner product, scalar multiples preserve orthogonality, but not length. However, if you mod out by scalar multiples the notion of length disappears. The sum of elements also ceases to make sense, but we can still discuss geometry. This is ubiquitous in algebraic geometry, and in many senses projective space is algebraically more well behaved than affine space. Another way to characterize projective space is as the set of lines through the origin in a vector space.

You could also declare that all vectors are the same length. Again we lose the sum, and the geometric object we end up with is the sphere.

You have to lose something if you're not content to simply ignore the length and actually want the concept to no longer make sense, and in these cases you lose the sum.

Comment: That seems interesting, but the description you gave involves modding out by scalar multiples. From the tiny bits of projective geometry I've heard of, this seems common, but I find it displeasing. Is there a more axiomatic presentation that builds upwards rather than by stripping structure away from a preexisting object?

And in a sense, I am content "to simply ignore the length", but what I mean by that is that I'm looking for a construction of some sort of orthogonality structure where the length was never in there, rather than being there and having to be ignored.

Comment: @user https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_geometry

Comment: @user In projective space the length is not just ignored, it isn't there. You're identifying every length, so really you're talking about lines, which have infinite length.

Answer (score 0):

This is my own idea. It comes from the original meaning of the notion of orthogonality i.e. the notion of right angle and perpendicular lines. Recall that the angle is a right angle iff it is congruent to its supplementary angle. I'll define the notion of angle and congruence of angles in abstract normed vector space. Thus the definition works perfectly fine in $\mathbb{R}^n$. It doesn't involve the inner product.

Let $V$ be normed vector space. Let $\sim$ be a binary relation in $V\setminus\{0\}$ defined $$a\sim a' :\iff \exists_{x>0}a'=xa$$ It can be easily proved that $\sim$ is an equivalence relation. Equivalence classes will be called rays.

An unordered pair $\{A,B\}$ of two rays will be called an angle.

Now an angle $\{A,B\}$ is said to be congruent to an angle $\{C,D\}$ iff $$\|a-b\|=\|c-d\|$$ , where  $a,b,c,d$ are (unique) vectors such that  $$a\in A,b\in B, c\in C, d\in D$$and $$\|a\|=\|b\|=\|c\|=\|d\|=1$$

A vector $a\in V$ is said to be orthogonal to a vector $b\in V$ iff $a=0$ or $b=0$ or $a\neq 0\neq b$ and $\{[a]_{\sim},[b]_{\sim}\}$ is congruent to $\{[-a]_{\sim},[b]_{\sim}\}$.

It seems that in $\mathbb{R}^n$ this definition is equivalent to standard inner product definition. Not sure about other inner product spaces. Besides, I don't know the interpretation of this orthogonality in normed spaces which aren't inner product spaces.

Comment: This isn't quite what I'm looking for, because (in $\mathbb{R}^n$) this simply lets us define an inner product immediately. What I was looking for was more along the lines of imposing a structure on a vector space which lets us say "x is 3 times longer than y" without letting us say how long x is in itself. This would be equivalent to defining orthogonality without an inner product. I'd want this to be built ground-up, not by subtracting structure from norms or inner products. Obviously we could then impose an inner product if we chose, but it would be unique only up to a constant.

Comment: Well, I don't think it is possible to impose such a structure on a vector space (or even $\mathbb{R}^n$) without referring to metric. What I know is that for example  "x is 3 times longer that y" can be effectively defined within Hilbert's axioms for geometry (very much in the spirit of Euclid). In Hilbert's axioms as a primitive notion we have congruence relation which lets us say that the distance from a to b is the same as the distance from c to d (without metric or real numbers). The next definitions are based on this notion. In vector space without metric however there is no such thing.